# Search for tab and replace it with active one

Tags: php, jquery, post, button, tabs

**Problem:**

To search for tab containing class "active" and remove it while adding an "active" class to current tab on PHP POST submission.

I have a tab menu that looks like this.

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="pull-right special-search" id="navtabs">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <a href="#tab1" class="active btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Start</a>
        <a href="#tab2" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-book icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Essay</a>
        <a href="#tab3" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-ok-sign icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Criteria</a>
        <a href="#tab4" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab"><i class="icon-time icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Activity</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**To toggle between these tabs I use the following jQuery code:**

```
$('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    e.target;
    e.relatedTarget;
    $('#navtabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('class','btn btn-info');
    $(this).attr('class','active btn btn-info');
})
```

**So far, so good. Everything works.** Now, when I press a button say "submit-updatetime" I want it to be checked with PHP that correspondent to what tab it was sent from. I do this by using a hidden type field:

```
<input type="hidden" id="submit_button" name="button_pressed">
```

**And then check it with PHP by using the following code:**

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    {
        $button = $_POST['button_pressed'];

        if ($button == 'submit-updategrades')
            $tabname = 'tab2';
        else if ($button == 'submit-updatetime')
            $tabname = 'tab4';
    }
?>
```

To make sure that the user stays on the tab he/she was on I use the following PHP/jQuery:

```
<?php           
    if (!empty($tabname))
    {
        echo '$("#navtabs a[href=#tab1]").removeClass(\'active\');';
        echo '$("#tab1").removeClass(\'active\');';
        echo '$("#navtabs a[href=#'.$tabname.']").addClass(\'active\');';
        echo '$("#'.$tabname.'").addClass(\'active\');';
    }
?>
```

This works just fine except that I feel that my last PHP/jQuery solution is flawed. For instance, the #tab1 is only active when you enter the page, not necessarily all the time.

**Question:**

How do I in the last PHP/jQuery code search for the tab that has the class "active" and remove it while at the same time add it to the active tab produced with $tabname?

Comment: Does the page reload after the _button gets pressed_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ho wo to find tab that has an `active` class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tab = $('#navtabs a.active');
});
```

Remove that `active` class on tab found:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tab = $('#navtabs a.active');
    tab.removeClass('active');
});
```

Find, remove and add `active` class to a tab provided from PHP:

```
<?php           
if (!empty($tabname)) { ?>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var active_tab = '#<?php echo $tabname; ?>';
    var tab = $('#navtabs a.active');
    tab.removeClass('active');
    $('#navtabs a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == active_tab) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            return;
        }
    });
});
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing the active tab verification before the HTML output, a simple solution with no script can be performed:

**PHP Active Tab Verification**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  // clear the variable from undesirable contents
  $button = strip_tags(trim($_POST['button_pressed']));

  // reset variables
  $tab1 = $tab2 = $tab3 = $tab4 = '';

  // check the variable contents
  switch ($button) {
    case "submit-updategrades": $tab2 = 'active'; break;
    case "submit-updatetime":   $tab4 = 'active'; break;
    default:                    $tab1 = 'active'; break;
  }
}
?>
```

**Note:** *Add to the `switch` the `case` you need to match. `$tab3` isn't present because you haven't mentioned on the question.*

**OUTPUT THE HTML WITH THE PROPER ACTIVE TAB**

```
<?php
echo '
<div class="pull-right special-search" id="navtabs">
  <div class="btn-group">
    <a href="#tab1" class="'.$tab1.' btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab">
      <i class="icon-home icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Start
    </a>
    <a href="#tab2" class="'.$tab2.' btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab">
      <i class="icon-book icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Essay
    </a>
    <a href="#tab3" class="'.$tab3.' btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab">
      <i class="icon-ok-sign icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Criteria
    </a>
    <a href="#tab4" class="'.$tab4.' btn btn-info" data-toggle="tab">
      <i class="icon-time icon-white"></i>&nbsp;Activity
    </a>
  </div>
</div>';
?>
```

Like this, you don't need to perform any post actions with jQuery to find and replace the active tab from your HTML. You are actually sending the HTML already prepared to the browser.